# Automate SFTP activation on ADLS

Tags: python, azure, automation, sftp

I have an Azure datalake storage account. On the Azure web interface, I can activate or deactivate the SFTP :
[image: Azure screen]

I there a possibility to activate or deactivate SFTP using python ?

I found something using bard but that's not working :

```
from azure.storage.filedatalake import ADLSFileSystemClient

client = ADLSFileSystemClient.from_connection_string("connection_string")

client.set_sftp_access("my-filesystem", True)
```

Error :

> ImportError: cannot import name 'ADLSFileSystemClient' from 'azure.storage.filedatalake' (lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/storage/filedatalake/**init**.py)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a possibility to activate or deactivate SFTP using Python?

You can use the code below to  **`Enable and disable`** SFTP using Azure Python SDK.

**Code:**(Enable)

```
from azure.mgmt.storage import StorageManagementClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
subscription_id="Your-subscription-id"
storage_client = StorageManagementClient(credential, subscription_id)

resource_group_name = "your-resource-grp-name"
storage_account_name = "your-storage-account-name"

credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
storage_client = StorageManagementClient(credential, subscription_id)

# Get the current properties of the storage account
storage_account = storage_client.storage_accounts.get_properties(
    resource_group_name, storage_account_name
)

# Enable SFTP for the storage account
storage_account.is_sftp_enabled=True
updated_storage_account=storage_client.storage_accounts.update(
    resource_group_name, storage_account_name, storage_account
)
print("Updated Storage Account Properties:")
print(f"Name: {updated_storage_account.name}")
print(f"Is SFTP Enabled: {updated_storage_account.is_sftp_enabled}")
```

**Output:**

```
Updated Storage Account Properties:
Name: venkat098
Is SFTP Enabled: True
```

[image]

[image]

Similarly, In the above code if you change **`storage_account.is_sftp_enabled=False`** it will disable the SFTP in the Azure storage account.

**Reference:**

[Python Examples of azure.mgmt.storage.StorageManagementClient (programcreek.com)](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/118575/azure.mgmt.storage.StorageManagementClient)

Comment: thanks. I'm gonna test and let you know